std::nearbyint does not round to nearest while std::rint does
I want to round a double to the nearest integer and round to even in halfway cases. Per documentation std::nearbyintf should do this:

If the current rounding mode is FE_TONEAREST, this function rounds to even in halfway cases (like std::rint, but unlike std::round).

Another function that does this is std::rintf. The docs of std::rintf state:

The only difference between std::nearbyint and std::rint is that std::nearbyint never raises FE_INEXACT.

So, I did expect the same results for both functions, but they return different results for double x = 3.4999999.
The following reprex demonstrates this:
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cfenv>
#include <cmath>

int main() {
  std::fesetround(FE_TONEAREST);

  std::cout << std::setprecision(15)
            << " std::nearbyintf(3.5) = " << std::nearbyintf(3.5) << "\n"
            << " std::rint(3.5) = " << std::rint(3.5) << std::endl;

  std::cout << std::setprecision(15)
            << " std::nearbyintf(2.5) = " << std::nearbyintf(2.5) << "\n"
            << " std::rint(2.5) = " << std::rint(2.5) << std::endl;

  std::cout << std::setprecision(15)
            << " std::nearbyintf(3.4999999) = " << std::nearbyintf(3.4999999) << "\n"
            << " std::rintf(3.4999999) = " << std::rint(3.4999999) << std::endl;
            
  return 0;
}

This example can be run here and produces the following output:
 std::nearbyintf(3.5) = 4
 std::rint(3.5) = 4
 std::nearbyintf(2.5) = 2
 std::rint(2.5) = 2
 std::nearbyintf(3.4999999) = 4
 std::rintf(3.4999999) = 3

Any advice on why they differ would be greatly appreciated.

Your live demo does not work for me. You can consider to replace with this Godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/z/Mroz3zT86.

Thanks, I replaced the URL with the godbolt example.

I expect the answer to be something crazy, of type "the value of 3.4999999 can't be represented as float with such precision, and it rounded to 3.5" :)

The reason is a typo: You called std::rint, when you wanted to test std::rintf. The former will operate in double precision, in which 3.4999999 happens to round to a value below 3.5 (while exactly 3.5 when rounding to float).

@user17732522 you mean (alternatively) typo is in using std::nearbyintf instead of std::nearbyint. https://godbolt.org/z/MaesWr8sj

BTW cppinsiths nicely exposes this issue: https://cppinsights.io/s/8319d2b5

Change << " std::rintf(3.4999999) = " << std::rint(3.4999999) << std::endl; to << " std::rintf(3.4999999) = " << std::rintf(3.4999999) << std::endl; and your bug goes away.  Casting 3.499999 to float changes how it rounds.
